# Date range report by scratchpad in amazon mws for daily basis order report using custom transaction type?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral, scratchpad

> I am able to get this report by Amazon Seller Central UI. 
>   Using these steps-
>   Sign in to your Merchant Account on Seller Central. Click the Date Range Reports tab, and then click Generate Report. In the Generate date range report dialog box, enter the following settings, as applicable: In the Please select a report type field, Transaction is pre-selected
>
> But from amazon MWS scratchpad it is difficult to get the report because I don't know the report type.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little late on this one but I came across the same issue and I think others may benefit from the answer.

The enum for this report is: `_GET_DATE_RANGE_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTION_DATA_`

You cannot *request* this report from the API, but you can download it through the API if you request it beforehand in the Seller Central UI as you describe above.  Note that one must use the `GetReportList` operation rather than the `GetReportRequestList` operation to find the report for download as it will not be in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [report types](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports).  Try to find one that sounds like a match, run it from scratchpad and compare it to the one generated from seller central.  In my experience, it was trial-and-error.  Note that some reports might not be available from the MWS API.

Comment: You might try opening a case with the MWS team.  I have done that in the past and they were able to help.